# R Markdown with \newif fails to compile to pdf after update

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

After the latest update to RStudio "Ghost Orchid" (Build 372) the RMarkdown below fails to compile to pdf on macOS Monterey. An identical file compiles fine on a different machine running previous versions of both RStudio and macOS ("Juliet Rose" (Version 1.4.1717), macOS Big Sur).

Any help to fix the problem is highly appreciated, thanks!

````
---
title: "minimalTest"
output: pdf_document
---

``` {r, include = F}
solution <- TRUE 
    ```

\newif\ifsol
\sol`r ifelse(solution, 'true', 'false')`

# Simple example of non-compiling code

\ifsol

Text to conditionally skip

\fi
````